# Mongo db Aggregate match a sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to return all records that are owned by a particular user. I can get it to return the values as expected when i query the mongodb using terminal but when i try and get results via a server side node

the object

```
{ { "_id" : ObjectId("562820793089576b064a4e9c"),
 "record" : ObjectId("562813a2d6f390ec585490bb"),
 "user" : ObjectId("561c00a49ae9f2e340aa3a6b"),
 "AuditItems" : [ ...],
 "AuditType" : [ "update" ],
 "created" : ISODate("2015-10-21T23:32:09.256Z"),
 "__v" : 0 }
```

When i make this query against the terminal i get the results i want:

```
db.audits.aggregate([{
    $match:{"user":ObjectId("561c00a49ae9f2e340aa3a6b")}},
    { $group: { _id: {$dateToString: { format: "%m/%d/%Y", date: "$created" }}, dataPoints: {$sum: {$size: "$AuditItems"}} } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } 
}])
```

results:

```
{ "_id" : "10/21/2015", "dataPoints" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "10/22/2015", "dataPoints" : 11 }
{ "_id" : "10/24/2015", "dataPoints" : 1 }
```

However when i make this request via a server side node controller it returns the error: **returned: MongoError: Maximum call stack size exceededundefined**

```
db.audits.aggregate([{
    $match:{"user":req.user}},
    { $group: { _id: {$dateToString: { format: "%m/%d/%Y", date: "$created" }}, dataPoints: {$sum: {$size: "$AuditItems"}} } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } 
}])
```

where req.user is the object looked up from the path "/api/user/audits/:userId/edits"

FYI i'm using the :userid path template everywhere else with success i also can simply remove the $match line and get a successful response. I'm somehow missing the problem on the line:

```
 $match:{"user":req.user}},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course as usual, the moment I posted it I found the answer:

```
 $match:{"user":req.user._id}},
```

passing the entire object is unnecessary  and simply required that I pass the id of the object to match it.

thanks for watching...

Comment: Can you mark it is as "Solved", if the issue is solved already.